# ASUS ZenBook Pro UX550VE Can't Install OS, Goes Straight to TTY1 and Can't Use sudo Commands

Tags: boot, laptop, live-installation

I am trying to install Elementary OS on my ASUS ZenBook Pro UX550VE. I have disabled fast boot and secure boot in BIOS. I used a 32 GB flash drive and flashed it with the ISO file using Rufus. When I boot to the live CD, I get the grub menu. I removed the splash and quiet parameters to see what is going on, since it would get stuck on the splash screen. It prompts me to log in using tty1, no GUI whatsoever. I login with the username elementary and no password, no problem. However, whenever I try to enter a sudo command the system freezes. Every once in a while I also get `watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#X stuck for Xs!` and some other suspicious looking messages. I am wondering if this is an issue with my GPU since it has integrated and a GTX 1050 Ti, but I can not install NVIDIA drivers because it just freezes. Anyone know something I can try?

Comment: Also a note that I can install Ubuntu 18.04.1 no problem, which is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding nomodeset to the boot options in GRUB